# WooCommerce Product get_stock_quantity() method return null

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, stock, product-quantity

I have a problem when I try to retrieve the available quantity of a product in my view.

This is my code :

```
function wcs_custom_get_availability( $availability, $_product ) {
    global $product;

    // Change In Stock Text
    if ( $_product->is_in_stock() ) {
        $availability['availability'] = __( 'Plenty available in our store!', 'woocommerce');
    }
         
    // Change in Stock Text to only 1 or 2 left
    if ( $_product->is_in_stock() && $product->get_stock_quantity() <= 2 ) {
        $availability['availability'] = sprintf( __('Only %s left in store!', 'woocommerce'), $product->get_stock_quantity() );
    }
         
    // Change Out of Stock Text
    if ( ! $_product->is_in_stock() ) {
        $availability['availability'] = __('Sorry, All sold out!', 'woocommerce');
    }
         
    return $availability;
}
```

The result of the execution is as follows : **Only left in store!**

I have access to the product variable but the result is null but I would like to retrieve the quantity.

Comment: May it should be `$_product->get_stock_quantity()`?

Answer (score 3):

Using `WC_Product` method `get_manage_stock()` with it, you will be able to avoid this problem. I have also simplified a bit your code:

```
 add_filter( 'woocommerce_get_availability', 'filter_wc_get_availability', 10, 2);
function filter_wc_get_availability( $availability, $product ) {
    // In Stock
    if ( $product->is_in_stock() ) {
        $stock_quantity = $product->get_stock_quantity();

        // Change Text for low stock (1 or 2 left)
        if ( $product->get_manage_stock() && $stock_quantity == ( 1 || 2 ) ) {
            $availability['availability'] = sprintf( __('Only %s left in store!', 'woocommerce'), $stock_quantity );
        } 
        // Change in Stock Text (when more than 2)
        else {
            $availability['availability'] = __( 'Plenty available in our store!', 'woocommerce');
        }
    }
    // Change Out of Stock Text
    else {
        $availability['availability'] = __('Sorry, All sold out!', 'woocommerce');
    }
         
    return $availability;
}
```

It should solve this problem.

> Don't use `global $product;` as for **variable products** it will take the variable product object instead of the variations of this variable product. The WC_Product object is already included in the function as an argument. **Stock is decreased on the products variatons and not on the parent variable product.**

Comment: Thank you for answering my question, but your solution doesn't work because you make invatl( NULL ) so the returned value is 0.

Comment: @sckraa Oups! yes… Updated… You should not use the global WC_product as it's included as an argument in the function…  For variable products the stock quantity should be the child product variations quantity only and not the parent variable product quantity.

Comment: This works for me, except on variable products. I get PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught Error: Call to a member function get_stock_quantity() on string in ... $stock = $product->get_stock_quantity();

Answer (score 3):

Correction :

Replace `$product->get_stock_quantity()` by `$_product->get_stock_quantity()`.

```
function wcs_custom_get_availability( $availability, $_product ) {
    global $product;
    // Change In Stock Text
    if ( $_product->is_in_stock() ) {
        $availability['availability'] = __( 'Plenty available in our store!', 'woocommerce');
    }
         
    // Change in Stock Text to only 1 or 2 left
    if ( $_product->is_in_stock() && $_product->get_stock_quantity() <= 2 ) {
        $availability['availability'] = sprintf( __('Only %s left in store!', 'woocommerce'), $_product->get_stock_quantity() );
    }
         
    // Change Out of Stock Text
    if ( ! $_product->is_in_stock() ) {
        $availability['availability'] = __('Sorry, All sold out!', 'woocommerce');
    }
         
    return $availability;
}
```

Comment: This worked for my site, on both regular products, and variable products.

Comment: Deosn't work anymore, i get errors.

Answer (score 0):

in my case none of the answers worked, so I figured it out by myself. The thing is you should check first if `managing_stock()` is on. If it is, then we're good to go.

So, the final code is:

```
/**
* Change the test for "In Stock / Quantity Left / Out of Stock".
*/

add_filter( 'woocommerce_get_availability', 'wcs_custom_get_availability', 1, 2);
function wcs_custom_get_availability( $availability, $_product ) {
   global $product;

    // Change In Stock Text
    if ( $_product->managing_stock() && $_product->is_in_stock() ) {
        echo '<p class="store-inside__number">';
            $availability['availability'] = __( 'Plenty available in our store!', 'woocommerce');
        echo '</p>';
    }

    // Change in Stock Text to only 1 or 2 left
    if ( $_product->managing_stock() && $_product->is_in_stock() && $_product->get_stock_quantity() <= 2 ) {
        $availability['availability'] = sprintf( __('Only %s left in store!', 'woocommerce'), $_product->get_stock_quantity() );
    }

    // Change Out of Stock Text
    if ( $_product->managing_stock() && ! $_product->is_in_stock() ) {
        $availability['availability'] = __('Sorry, All sold out!', 'woocommerce');
    }

    return $availability;
}
```